# Emmet in Eclipse Mars expands css abbreviations into xml (html) tags

Tags: eclipse

I'm used to Emmet in IntelliJ, and I've always really liked how it increases workflow. Now that I'm using Eclipse, I can't get Emmet to work properly.

When I type `posa [tab]` in my .scss file (scss **is** in the list of 'Expand abbreviations by tab key ...in files with extensions: '), I'd expect to get `position: absolute;`. Instead, I get `<posa></posa>`. `p5px` becomes `<p5px></p5px>`, etcetera.

I uninstalled and reinstalled the Emmet plugin, but to no avail. I've tried to Restore Defaults on the Preferences -> General, Emmet and Web menu options, this didn't help either. It works fine in css and html, just not in scss.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, nevermind.

Turns out my Eclipse never actually identified *.scss as being a css-file. So, what I already had was Preferences > General > Content Types, where I added the *.scss to File Associations.

What I just now added is the CSS Editor (make default) for *.scss files (via Add...) in Preferences > Editors > File Associations.

Works fine now.